# How to pass parameters to function using buttons

Tags: javascript

I have several buttons that use the same implementation but need to pass a different parameter to the function.  This if for an mp3 player for context.  My idea should be easy to follow, but I cannot get the syntax to work.  Hope someone can help.

The button in HTML:

```
<input id="songToPlay" type="button" value="Click To Play!"/>
```

Then the javascript onclick call:

```
document.getElementById('songToPlay').onclick = playSongByThisBand;
```

The method playSongByThatBand():

```
function playSongByThisBand() {
    playSongByAnyBand(theIntegerThatRepresentsThisBand);
}
```

The method playSongByAnyBand(parameter):

```
function playSongByAnyBand(anIntegerThatRepresentsABand) {
    currentSongIndex=anIntegerThatRepresentsABand;
    //other implementation ect...
}
```

An alternative approach I tried is:

```
function playSongByAnyBand(anIntegerThatRepresentsABand) {
    currentSongIndex=anIntegerThatRepresentsABand;
    someObject = function() {other implementation ect...}
}

var functionIWantToExecutre = new playSongByAnyBand(anIntegerThatRepresentsABand)

functionIWantToExecute.someObject();
```

I cannot get playSongByAnyBand to execute.  I could implement each button separately but that is even more redundant that my approach already.  Can anyone help me with the syntax to implement multiple buttons this way?

Comment: Where does `anIntegerThatRepresentsABand` come from?

Comment: The button that gets pressed needs to inform the function by passing an argument.  It looks like I can pass the argument from the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### By Javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="playSong('param1')" />
```

---

```
function playSong(param) {
    // do something
}
```

### With jQuery

```
<input type="button" value="Play" id="btnPlay" data-param="param1" />
```

---

```
$("#btnPlay").click(function() {
    var param = $(this).data("param");
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button specify the band as a data attribute :

```
<input id="songToPlay" 
       type="button" 
       value="Click To Play!"
       data-band="bandName" />
```

The in your event handler yoiu can fetch it thus :

```
function playSong (ev) {
   var song = this.id;
   var band = this.getAttribute ('data-band');

   // .. put your play code for band/song rght here

}
```

Another way of accessing the `data-band` attribute is using the `dataset` a relatively new HTML feature now available on most current browsers.

```
function playSong (ev) {
   var song = this.id;
   var band = this.dataset.band; // Fetches attribute 'data-band'

   // .. put your play code for band/song rght here

}
```

You can add as many `data-xxx` attributes as you like for different infos. Each is a string value.